# Softlayer Python API - add_standard_firewall function throws error

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liora/git/radiomize/spinup_env.py", line 13, in 
    spinup()
  File "/Users/liora/git/radiomize/python-modules/functions.py", line 27, in spinup
    infra()
  File "/Users/liora/git/radiomize/python-modules/functions.py", line 102, in infra
    fwi = fw_mgr.add_standard_firewall(vsi[0]['id'],is_virt=True)
  File "/Users/liora/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/managers/firewall.py", line 104, in add_standard_firewall
    package = self.get_standard_package(server_id, is_virt)
  File "/Users/liora/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/managers/firewall.py", line 55, in get_standard_package
    firewall_port_speed = self._get_fwl_port_speed(server_id, is_virt)
  File "/Users/liora/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/managers/firewall.py", line 173, in _get_fwl_port_speed
    fwl_port_speed = primary['primaryNetworkComponent']['maxSpeed']
KeyError: 'primaryNetworkComponent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to **add_standard_firewall**:

```
import SoftLayer

# Define your SoftLayer's username and apiKey
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Create a SoftLayer API client object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)


# Define the vsi's identifier
vsi_id = 18382333
# Define Firewall Manager
fw_mgr = SoftLayer.FirewallManager(client)
try:
    result = fw_mgr.add_standard_firewall(vsi_id, is_virt=True)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error: faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
                % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

I'm using SoftLayer Python API Client 5.2.0 and Python 2.7.12

**References**:

- [SoftLayer API Python Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python)

Comment: I am calling the function just after the instance created. Do I need to wait till it is ready and only then call the add_standard_firewall function?

Comment: BTW, how do I check which SoftLayer API Python Client I am using?

Comment: This is the updated error: Error: faultCode=SoftLayer_Exception_Public, faultString=Hardware firewalls are not available for hourly-billed servers.

Comment: That's right, you need to wait until the VM has been already provisioned, then you can add the standard firewall, you can use [wait_for_ready](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/managers/vs.py#L393) to check when the vsi is ready. One way to check the Python Client version is opening a command prompt and execute: **slcli --version**

Comment: I think that I need to configure the dedicated firewall for my virtual machine (which is not bare metal)

Comment: Hardware firewalls are only available for monthly billed servers, so it means that the server that you tried is billed by hour